# How do I traverse a matrix in assembly?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, matrix, x86

I did a matrix 3x3 with random numberns in C and now i want to verify the pairs of this matrix in assembly calling the function count_pairs_matrix(int **m, int y, int k).

y --> are the number of rows

k --> are the number of columns

I'm doing this:

```
movl 8(%ebp), %eax  #pointer m
movl 12(%ebp), %ebx #k
movl 16(%ebp), %ecx #y
movl $0, %esi

(..)
movl (%eax,%esi,4), %edx  <-- the problem is here, the register edx have the address but not the number of that position of the matrix
```

Comment: You'd need to dereference `%edx` with something like `movl (%edx), %edx` after `movl (%eax,%esi,4), %edx`

Comment: That's AT&T x86x syntax, not [NASM Syntax](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/NASM_Syntax).

Comment: Does the `int **m` in the prototype mean you're really representing your 3x3 matrix with an array of 3 pointers to arrays of 3 integers?  That's a huge waste of space compared to `int m[3][3]`.  In asm, it's the difference between having to dereference twice, or having to calculate `i*k + j` to get the right offset into the one block of memory.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is gas syntax, not nasm syntax.

Second of all, the matrix iteration looks like something else. Assuming a straight 2d array (not array of array),

```
    movl 8(%ebp), %eax  #pointer m
    movl 12(%ebp), %ebx #k
    movl 16(%ebp), %ecx #y

    mull %ebx
    movl %eax, %esi

.l  movl (%esi), %edx
    (and process)
    addl $4, %esi
    decl %ebx
    jnz  .l
```